# BigHow.com is copying SO content

Tags: support, legal, copycat-sites

[These guys](http://bighow.net/6022046-Angle_brackets_and__.html) are posting question text without any attribution whatsoever, unless you count semi-hidden links to the original SO question to be "attribution". I don't!

Comment: declare war on them!

Comment: This is not the place to report scrapers. See [Updated procedure for reporting SCRAPERs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers)

Comment: I love going out of my way to help the SE team and being essentially told to f@#! off and put more effort into it. Screw it.

Comment: @animuson's response seems to be spot on, and nicael seems to be joking around. I see no "eff off" in that...

Comment: BRB, getting you a cookie...

Comment: No one's telling you to f@#! off. Animuson posted the link where these are posted.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: No, he posted a link to instructions to follow another link to find a form, to provide all the same information again. But I've done my part.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Perhaps there is some research that tell SE that scrapping would only help in increasing the traffic on the site.  Screw it, lets not do it.  (The last line is a modified version of a text by R. Branson.)